# Generate complex (non-convex) polyhedron UV mapping

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, 3d, computational-geometry

I need to find an approach to the problem of generating texture maps for non-convex polyhedrons without using a design tool. Specifically, I am mapping simulation results data onto a 3D surface. That is, in code (C# or VB preferably, since my target is WPF 3D).

One generic approach uses a `GradientBrush` to just map colors (as in the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881576/wpf-3d-mapping-gradient-brush-on-complex-geometry)), but if the facets in the polyhedron are very narrow or the mapped (u,v) coordinates are very far apart on the same facet, the image gets noisy.

Are there any C#/.NET libraries (commercial or otherwise) applicable to this? In my research I've come across the term "atlas unwrapping", the descriptions of which sound like what I need.

In the absence of prewritten libraries, what articles or books would contain descriptions of the algorithm?

(I am familiar with the basics of 3D graphics and texture mapping, so there will be no need to supply a basic tutorial for that. If you want to leave a link to something like that in the comments, knock yourself out.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sound to me you don't want Atlas unwrapping. I think atlas unwrapping is something like nested uv mapping.  But Uv-unwrapping and Least-Squares Conformal map is a similar technology. There is also angle based flattening. You can find some papers here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17779/c-c-code-to-generate-texture-coordinates-for-a-curved-surface.

Comment: This is an answer which guides me to papers and algorithms. They all look like they're beyond the intermediate programmer's level, and none are easy to implement. But the other two responses so far are not answers to the specific question. Bounty awarded here.

Answer (score 1):

if the mesh is symmetrical enough

You could try to convert **vertex** coordinates to **cylindric space**  around **mesh axis** and use the **angle** as texture coordinate (Red). The second one (blue/aqua) would be the **surface distance** from **zero plane**.

I would select the plane intersecting **mesh center** after this you should translate/scale the texture coordinates so they match your rendering engine specifications.

The disadvantage is **distortion** around cylindric poles and the advantage is that convexity doesn't matter

[image: cylindric style mesh texturing]

Comment: That's a good algorithm, but it's not atlas mapping. Think of a triangle mesh of an American gallon milk jug. You can't do a cylinder unwrap of that.

Comment: well i have no idea how that bottle looks like but unless your mesh is complex with holes then this should work. the thing is only how much space distorted the texture will be. btw you have not specified the shape of your mesh and the mapping purpose (you know the texture or you create a texture from voxel-map ... )

Comment: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-ibh3grqOdmY/TVYFgW-B5NI/AAAAAAAAB-A/hey3kisJsNc/s1600/Feb+9+2011+040.jpg is a picture of an American gallon milk container. Google would have been your friend.

Comment: Yeap contains holes,... this approach is not good for that. Unfortunately i am not shore if there even is an automated way to do uniform surface mapping of universal complex mesh with holes. May be can help  some surface flood-fill until all surface is covered or fill ends (then uncovered part must be done as next texture - mesh division) but to code that will be probably a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the CGAL library. It has many facilities for 3D mathematics. I used it in my masters, but I haven't done that in a long time.

http://www.cgal.org/

Comment: It has many facilities for 3D geometry, most limiting use under the GPL (which is not a deal breaker!) But, WHICH portions of CGAL contain algorithms for atlas mapping?

Comment: It has facilities for non-convex polyhedra generation and triangulation. I thought this could help.

Comment: We're starting with a pre-generated, already triangulated non-convex polyhedron. It might help but the library is very large...