# Applying textures on 3D geometric shapes

Tags: xna, geometry, xna-4.0, computational-geometry, procedural-generation

I have a question that is bothering me for weeks! Is there any way of applying textures to 3D convex polygons, independently of their orientation in the 3D world. I am working with XNA 4.0 if it's relevant

I'm not expecting an easy way out, just a clean solution to solve my current problem. Does anyone made something similar to that?!

Thanks in advance, for your concern and time!

Comment: Texture mapping is typically done in model space, so as the model orients itself the texture moves with the object as you'd expect.  Do you mean this or something different?

Comment: as @MarPing comments, model space texturing technique is the usual way of applying textures, and it implies that the orientation of the model is irrelevant

Comment: in other way, you can apply transformations to your texture coords to rotate the texture... if your texture coords for a square (has 4 vertex) are (0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(0,1), you can rotate the texture 90º changing them to (1,0),(0,0),(1,1),(0,1)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Blau! I'm working with geometry generated on the fly and not with pre created models. Thereby, your second comment is more close to the solution that I'm searching. However the texture  with this coordinates (0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(0,1) will have to wrap a shape with arbitrary points in space. It can be, for example a pentagon in the ground (with X,Z definition) or a rectangular wall (with X,Y,Z definitions). Do you have any suggestion? Thanks a lot for your comment :)

Comment: I would also like to thank Mark for his comment. What I'm trying to do is to apply textures to my own geometry. Imagine a wall or a roof of a house. These elements typically may have different orientation in both XX and YY axis. I can't find a way of texturing this elements properly. Was this explanation suffice to clarify my question? Once again, thank you very much. I really appreciate your feedback! (This comment was reedited in order to rectify "match" to "much". I was trying to say "thank you very much" and not "match"! Sorry about that. My english is too close from awful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automated generation texture coordinates for shapes is not easy... I have an idea that is not the best, but maybe it help you

if the shape lays in a plane you can create a square that contains the shape, is easy to get the texture coordinates in [0..1] range interpolating vertex positions inside the square in the plane.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Blau, for your time and effort. I'm still trying to "decode" your explanation but this is just because I have some limitations related with maths and geometry (you can read as "a little bit dumb :) "). Anyway, I'll put the check on your answer 'cause I belive it's the right way for achieving the expected results! Thank you very much and good luck mate :) And sorry about the bother!

Comment: I'm not satisfied with my explanation...it can be done much better... I will try again this night :)

Comment: I'm studying a solution based on normal vectors. The idea is to calculate the difference between the normal angle of each plane and the X axis and Y axis in order to apply a matrix transformation that should favor the calculations of the texture vertices. Do you consider this a reliable solution?

Comment: Check the new drawing with new explanation... I think is clearer

Comment: I think the solution you propose is feasible... it depends on what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Something similar is also here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19004944/2521214

- worth looking also the whole thread (question and all comments including)
- not just my answer